# Is there any notebook software that allows copypasting images?

Tags: software-recommendation, evernote

I was a big fan of Microsoft OneNote for taking notes in class. I've tried to look for an option in Ubuntu.
I tried Joplin and SimpleNote but none of them allows this.
Do you know any opensource option?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [cherrytree](https://www.giuspen.com/cherrytree/).

It is [available in the official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cherrytree&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) for bionic(18.04), hirsute(21.04) and impish(21.10), install with

```
sudo apt install cherrytree
```

There also exists a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Egiuspen/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=focal) which provides a slightly newer version and provides packages for focal (20.04), in this case install with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:giuspen/ppa
sudo apt install cherrytree
```

Answer (score 0):

[Zim](https://zim-wiki.org/) is another excellent option.

You can install it from the official software sources (`sudo apt install zim`).

Comment: but I think Zim does not allow copy pasting. The user needs to import the image as a file.

Comment: Yes it does, at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xournal++.

[image: xopp]

You can install it with its stable PPA, which supports Ubuntu 18.04 and above.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/xournalpp-stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xournalpp
```

Other installation options (appimage, snap, flatpak, .deb) are also [available](https://xournalpp.github.io/installation/linux/).

It also supports graphics tablets.